# Treatment of large size packets at Twisted

Tags: python, multithreading, tcp, twisted, serve

I am currently building a TCP server (the server is going to be used by my company so it must be at a high production level)

My requirements are:

1. The server will be fast (it can handle a large number of requests simultaneously because our clients send large files regularly and this will create Bottleneck).
2. The server will be easy to maintain.
3. Support as many users as possible at the same time.
4. That the server will be a TCP server because it receives protocol messages that our company has developed and I need to parse it myself.

After checking the options, I chose Python Twisted because he seems to be meeting the first requirement (and since he is in Python then the second demand is solved by itself).

After reading Twisted's documentation I thought of a problem I had not yet found an elegant answer , my clients send me pretty large packets and I make decisions based sub sequence within these packets.

Let's say if I got 1000 first bytes that are all zeros and then another 5,000 bytes that all of them 0x10, I will send back "Hello world" and if I get instead 2000 bytes that all of them 0x50 I will answer "Hello everyone".

My problem with Twisted is that the data eventually comes to "protocol.Protocol" and they are treated with the "dataReceived (self, data)" function, and this instant is a one-time instant, which means that if I only get some of the bytes for the first time and I'm going to get the rest of the bytes at the second time I do not have how to save the data from the first time...

I can not save the data in the protocol.Factory because I will talk with multiple clients simultaneously and then one will use the data of the other, for the same reason I can not use the Globals.

I'm pretty sure I'm not the first to come across this problem, I've seen several online solutions that included re-implementation of "protocol.Protocol" and they really were not elegant ..

Is there a simple and elegant way to solve this problem?
(The solution must be elegant because I add multi-threading over it since the things I give back to the client are much more than "Hello World" and I do not want to block the server)

By the way, if someone with experience can recommend for me on a better solution than Twisted I am more than happy.

Thank you

yoko

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to maintain some per connection state. That's the minimum amount you can store and still employ such a protocol. Your protocol class should be instantiated once per connection, so you should be able to use properties on that class to store things like `zeros_received` and `twos_received`.

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    if self.zeros_received != 1000:
        for x, b in enumerate(data):
            if b != 0x00:
                # Handle unexpected byte error
            self.zeros_received += 1

            if self.zeros_received == 1000:
                break

    if self.twos_received != 5000:
        for b in data[x+1:]:
            if b != 0x10:
                # handle unexpected byte error
            self.twos_received += 1

            if self.twos_received == 5000:
                break

   # send hello...
```

An easier solution would be to buffer the data from the client and then block (with a timeout on the connection) until you've received the first 6k bytes. I'd be careful about prematurely optimizing. You assume now this will be your bottleneck, but often your assumptions may be wrong. Implement a naive solution first (using a buffered reader) and then benchmark speed/memory usage and see what actually needs improving.

```
def dataReceived(self, data):
    self.data += data

    if len(self.data) >= 6000:
        assert all(lambda b: b == 0x00, self.data[:1000]), 'expected 0x00'
        assert all(lambda b: b == 0x10, self.data[1000:6000]), 'expected 0x10'

        # send hello
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.
I apologize if I did not explain myself correctly, I am looking for a generic solution to the problem of maintaining per connection state and not a specific solution for the example I brought (I brought it as an example only is not really my protocol) . I can not use the solution you suggested in case I have a state machine that is based on the first 100K bytes, because if I implement it I will completely block my server and lose the ability to handle multiple clients simultaneously.

Comment: There are no generic solutions to this. I was trying to illustrate that you can store the state for a protocol without having to store the first 6k bytes. My first example is a FSM that handles such a protocol with only needing to store 2 numbers. You can't get away with storing no state in all. But it sounds like you may have a misunderstanding about how twisted works. Twisted uses an event loop. It handles multiple connections at once. One connection will not hold up another because there are no blocking reads due to how `dataReceived` is invoked.

Comment: "Put stuff on self" is exactly the generic solution to the problem of maintaining per connection state.  If your protocol isn't as described in the question, that just means you'll do different stuff with `data` and put different "stuff" on self.